# Leavitt Path Algebras and Direct Sum

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, ring-theory, abelian-groups

Let $A$ be an abelian group and $B, C$ be two subgroups of $A$ such that $A=B\oplus C$. Consider the canonical inclusions and projections $p_C,p_B,\pi_C,\pi_B$. We have the following relations: $\pi_Bp_B=1_B$, $\pi_Cp_C=1_C$, $\pi_Bp_C=0$, $\pi_Cp_B=0$ and $p_B\pi_B+p_C\pi_C=1_A$. If we identify all the "ones" and the "zeros" as maps we end up exactly with the CK1 CK2 relations of the Leavitt Path Algebra of the graph with one vertex and two petals. In this case $\pi_B,\pi_C$ are the ghost edges respectively of $p_B,p_C$. Hence in a certain sense, this decomposition of $A$ induces a Leavitt Path Algebra, in particular, the Leavitt algebra $L_{1,2}(\mathbb{K})$. More in general, the direct sum of $k$ subgroups will induce the algebra $L_{1,k}(\mathbb{K})$. I'm wondering if there is some sense behind this or if it is only a coincidence. Is there a similar construction for other types of decompositions of an abelian group?

(A similar thing appears when we consider an extension of groups $0\rightarrow M\xrightarrow{i} E\xrightarrow{\pi} G\rightarrow 0$. If we choose a section $s:G\rightarrow E$ we can naturally induce a map $\phi:E\rightarrow M$ such that $i,\pi,s,\phi$ verify similar relations as above).